# The process of identifying the parts of speech: Grammaring? Tagging?

Tags: sentence-structure, parts-of-speech

Sometimes occupied by life, others kept forgetting, I have always wondered what the process of identifying the parts of speech in a text is called? Grammaring? Tagging?

Tagging seems to be linked to corpus linguistics, and grammaring is by far a rare term- My Firefox spell checker marked it with a squiggly line.

Would you say I am teaching my son how to identify the parts of speech? I feel I'd catch my breath saying it!
At any case, what do students and teachers use at school?

Comment: "Tagging" is more than just identification; it tags POS tags to words. I think I'm fine with either *identification* or *classification*. I'm not sure what words a teacher would use when teaching young kids, though.

Comment: Identifying the 'parts of speech' is fine, though you can use 'word categories', like many grammarians do. We generally talk of analysing a clause, (call it syntactic analysis if you like), and each word or phrase is **assigned** two labels, a category label and a function label. Sometimes we talk of tree diagramming clauses

Comment: You can also say "I'm teaching my son how to **parse** a sentence".

Comment: Yes, I'd forgotten 'parse'; we don't hear it used much nowadays, but it's a spot-on term for the old (and fear-inducing) 'clause analysis'.

Comment: http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/partsspeechterm.htm#

Comment: @BillJ Thank you BillJ. Could you cite an example that shows what a category and a function label look like? As for tree diagramming, I think it is another term for Tree Parsing also mentioned by Peter below.
V.V., thanks for the link, it was informative.

Comment: To parse a sentence is to analyse it by breaking it down into its constituent parts such as clauses and phrases, as well as assigning function and category (part of speech) labels to the words and phrases. You were asking about identifying the parts of speech, which is just one stage in the parsing procedure. I'm not aware of a universal term for doing that, but we often simply talk of 'identifying the parts of speech' or "assigning part of speech labels".

Comment: In a simple example like _Ed likes cheese_, _Ed_ would be assigned the function label “subject” and the category label ‘noun’. _Cheese_ would be assigned the function label ‘object’ and the category label 'noun'. I’ve simplified that a bit, but I think you’ll get the idea.

Comment: @BillJ It couldn't be clearer. Function:Subj./Object. Category:Noun. Oh, thanks Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual term used when syntactically analysing text is

> **parse**
>
> The compiler found syntax errors while **parsing** the program before compiling it.
>   The teacher **parsed** the sentence as she diagrammed it.

alternatives descriptors might be

> analyse
>   decompose *(into its parts)*
>   break apart
>
> The teacher **analysed** the sentence as she diagrammed it.
>   The teacher **decomposed** the sentence as she diagrammed it.
>   The teacher **broke apart** the sentence as she diagrammed it.